# How to add a entity to collection inside another entity in Entity Framework asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two entities (`student`, `yogaspaceevent`). `Yogaspaceevent` which is like a exercise class, has a collection of students as `RegisteredStudents` and I want to be able to add students to this event to register them.

I tried a couple of things but can't seem to add a student to a yogaspaceevent, so maybe I'm not doing it correctly.

Question: do I need to create a whole new entity (say `registeredstudents`) to add students to a `yogaspaceevent`? Because I thought Entity Framework would somehow create this table for me or do some other magic under the hood to add a student to a event? The only solution I have is to create a `RegisteredStudent` entity and then EF will create a table. Is this the right solution?

Here are my two entities:

```
public class YogaSpaceEvent
{
    public int YogaSpaceEventId { get; set; }

    [Index] 
    public DateTime DateTimeScheduled { get; set; }
    public int AppointmentLength { get; set; }
    public int StatusEnum { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student.Student> RegisteredStudents { get; set; }   

    [Index]
    public int YogaSpaceRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("YogaSpaceRefId")]
    public virtual YogaSpace YogaSpace { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual StudentImage StudentImage { get; set; } //one-to-one
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string CatchPhrase { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Education { get; set; } //Serra High School, San Diego State Univesity

    public string Work { get; set; } // Taco Bell, Starbucks
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string WhyIPractice { get; set; }
    public StudentStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller where I want to add a student to an event but I get exceptions thrown.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterStudentForEvent(int eventId)
{
        try
        {
            Student student = _studentRepository.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId()); //User.Identity.GetUserId()
            if (student == null)
            {
                return Json( new { error = "notification", message = "You need an active student profile to register, please complete your student profile." });
            }

            var spaceEvent = _yogaSpaceEventRepository.Find(eventId);
            if (spaceEvent.RegisteredStudents == null)
            {
                spaceEvent.RegisteredStudents = new Collection<Student>(); // new EntityCollection<Student>(); neither of these two work, both throw exceptions
            }
            spaceEvent.RegisteredStudents.Add(student);

            _yogaSpaceEventRepository.Modify(spaceEvent);
            _yogaSpaceEventRepository.Save();

            // send email confirmation with a cancel link in it.

            return Json(new { error = "false", message = "Now registered!. A confirmation email has been sent. Have fun! " });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json( new { error = "true", message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Here are the two exceptions that are thrown when I try both methods above.

> The object could not be added to the EntityCollection or EntityReference. An object that is attached to an ObjectContext cannot be added to an EntityCollection or EntityReference that is not associated with a source object.

and

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

Comment: Side note: You probably want all of your persisted properties to be virtual, not just some of them.

Comment: do you mean "RegisteredStudents"?

Comment: If you are using dynamic proxies you want all properties to be virtual so that EF can use a generated proxy class to track changes that you make to the entity.

Comment: I have no idea what that means, can you please explain or point me to a link to read?

Comment: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/12/05/should-you-use-entity-framework-change-tracking-proxies/

Comment: @user1186050 ICollection<Student.Student> is that a typo or in your code?

Comment: no the first student is the namespace the second student is the object

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue.

Your above code seems to be correct , I think you have missed to specify the mapping in dbcontext.cs class which resulted in below error:

> The object could not be added to the EntityCollection or
>   EntityReference. An object that is attached to an ObjectContext cannot
>   be added to an EntityCollection or EntityReference that is not
>   associated with a source object.

I hope my below example could help you.

---

### Specialization (Parent Entity Class)

```
 [Table("M_Specialization")]
    public partial class Specialization : Entity
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int SID { get; set; }
        public string SCode { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SubSpecialization> SubSpecializationDetails { get; set; }
}
```

---

### Sub specialization (Child Entity Class)

```
[Table("M_SubSpecialization")]
    public partial class SubSpecialization : Entity
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public Int32 SuID { get; set; }
        public string SubCode { get; set; }
        public Int32 SID { get; set; }  // This is required in order to map between specialization and subspecialization

        [ForeignKey("SID")]
        public virtual Specialization Specialization { get; set; }
    }
```

---

### dbcontext.cs:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SubSpecialization>().HasRequired(c => c.Specialization)
      .WithMany(s => s.SubSpecializationDetails)
      .HasForeignKey(c => c.SID);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to define a many-to-many relationship between Student and YogaSpaceEvent.  The code you have created so far represents a one-to-many relationship.

An description of how to do that can be found [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First)

What you need to add to your code is:
- Add a ICollection property to your Student class
- In your dbcontext.OnModelCreating, add code to define the many-to-many relationship.

As far as I can see, your controller function is OK.

Comment: this isn't a many-to-many rel. It's a one-to-many rel. There is one event (class) and many registered students

Comment: @user1186050, then why do you think you need another entity?  If this is a one-to-many, then your students will be placed in the Students table (which you seem to already have) and instead of finding a student that already exists and connecting it to the YogaSpaceEvent, you should be adding a new Student to the RegisteredStudents collection.